# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of tensors

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, tensors, eigenvalues

I have a linear equation where the unknown is a matrix:

$$\sum_{pq} T_{ijpq}X_{pq} = \lambda X_{ij}$$

This is an eigenvalue problem for the tensor $T_{ijpq}$. Mathematica `Eigenvalues` and `Eigenvectors` allows me to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix, which means I have to flatten $T_{ijpq}$ before I can apply these functions. But then the eigenvectors will be flattened too, and it is not obvious to me how I can recover the $X_{pq}$.

I can think of a contrived way of doing this, but I feel it should not be that complicated in Mathematica.

Comment: "I can think of a contrived way of doing this" - would you mind posting the "contrived" method as a self-answer? Then people can propose improvements.

Comment: @J.M. The idea is to transform the pair of indices $i,j$ to a single index $a$, and the pair of indices $p,q$ to a single index $b$. In my application, $i$ and $p$ traverse the same range, from $1$ to $M$, while $j$ and $q$ traverse a range from $1$ to $N$. Then $a,b$ traverses a ranges from 1 to $M^2$ and from 1 to $N^2$, respectively. But it gets messy when one tries to do the index mapping in any specific way. I am trying do it like this now. Then to read the eigenvector one needs inverse index mappings.

Comment: @J.M. I think I found a good way to do it!

Comment: I had some typos in my previous comments. It should say: $a,b$ traverse the range from 1 to $MN$.

Comment: Does 'flattening' leave the eigenvalues intact ? I can't mathematically understand why that's the case. Can someone enlighten me regarding this perhaps.

Comment: I sort of understand what you said, but can you point out a reference which shows this. I tried proving mathematically, but it didn't seem easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found a simple way.

```
mat = Flatten[T, {{1,2},{3,4}}]
eig = Eigenvalues[mat]
eiv = Eigenvectors[mat]
```

Then reshape the eigenvectors using `ArrayReshape`:

```
ArrayReshape[#, {m,n}] & /@ eiv
```

where $m,n$ are the ranges of the indices $p,q$.

Answer (score 7):

I have only two improvements.

First, use `Eigensystem` instead of `Eigenvalues` and `Eigenvectors`. Otherwise, you compute the eigenvalues twice.

Second, instead of `Map`ping `ArrayReshape` onto `eiv`, you can apply it directly, which also improves performance. (This is less an issue because `Eigensystem` consumes most of the ressources.

```
n = 10;
m = 12;
T = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n, m, n}];
mat = Flatten[T, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}];
{eig, eiv} = Eigensystem[mat];
eiv = ArrayReshape[eiv, {m n, m, n}];
```

And here is a test

```
Norm[
 Table[
  Norm[
   Sum[T[[All, All, k, l]] eiv[[i, k, l]], {k, 1, m}, {l, 1, n}] - 
    eig[[i]] eiv[[i]],
   Infinity],
  {i, 1, m n}],
 Infinity]

(* 5.12285*10^-14 *)
```